# NTLM authentication working in Firefox but not working in IE for a PHP website

Tags: php, apache, internet-explorer, windows-7, single-sign-on

I have a PHP website hosted on Windows 7 using Apache. It is using **mod_auth_sspi** module for Single Sign On (SSO) using AD.

Site can be accessed at:

```
http://192.168.5.91:7889
```

In Firefox I have added the following entry in **network.automatic-ntlm-auth-auth.trusted.uris**

```
192.168.5.91:7889
```

[image]

It is working fine and the website doesn't prompt user to enter user/password.

I have also added the same entry in my IE Local Intranet zone (I think IE version is either 10 or 11) but the website sometimes prompt user to enter user/password and sometimes doesn't.

Like it prompts and I press Cancel button and then I press F5 and then it prompts again and then I Cancel again and press F5. After 2, 3 tries it opens site. But after that if I click on any link on page then it prompts again and then I have to do this exercise all over again i.e. every time cancel and then press F5.

[image]

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a typo on the name of the preference you mentioned.

It is `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` not `network.automatic-ntlm-auth-auth.trusted.uris`

Source:
https://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris